# Creating a requirements.txt without development dependencies

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi

In development often additional packages are needed which I have installed in my `venv`, which are not needed in production contrary to other packages I also installed in my `venv`. What's the cleanest way to produce a `requirements.txt` which does have all the requirements except the once I only need in development (like `mypy` or `autopep8`)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55450776/13704678) shows how to do it but the method is very cumbersome.

Comment: The main point off using a `requirements.txt` is to make use of it within a `virtualenv`, and that file has all the dependencies, are you wanting to know how to use it outside of the `virtualenv` or `venv`? See this [link](https://medium.com/@boscacci/why-and-how-to-make-a-requirements-txt-f329c685181e).

Comment: @FishingCode I want to know how to manage two venv's (and the resulting requirements.txt which is created with pip freeze), one for production and one for development which has additional packages.

Comment: What you coud do/look into is that, create two requirements.txt one for production and the other for development (which has more packages) and create some logic to determine which `virtualenv` should run which requirements.txt. You could do that with a `.bat` file, and if you require different python versions you could add that as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend using `pip-compile`, from https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/.

This lets you define an "in" file, `requirements.in`, which just lists your top-level dependencies, e.g.:

`requirements.in`:

```
flask
```

Then you generate the `requirements.txt` with `pip-compile`:

```
$ pip-compile --output-file=requirements.txt requirements.in
#
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile
# To update, run:
#
#    pip-compile --output-file=requirements.txt requirements.in
#
click==7.1.2              # via flask
flask==1.1.2              # via -r requirements.in
itsdangerous==1.1.0       # via flask
jinja2==2.11.2            # via flask
markupsafe==1.1.1         # via jinja2
werkzeug==1.0.1           # via flask
```

Then you can have separate `.in`/`.txt` files for different environments, like `test.in`/`test.txt`.

And finally, you can recursively include multiple requirements files, e.g.

`dev-requirements.txt`:

```
-r requirements.txt
-r test.txt
-r lint.txt
```

Comment: See also [this doc](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools#workflow-for-layered-requirements) for layered requirements.