# How to keep runtime and development `requirements_*.txt` up to date?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, requirements.txt

I would like to keep multiple `requirements*.txt` files up to date while working on a project. Some packages my project depends on are required at runtime, while others are required during development only. Since these packages may have their own dependencies as well, it is hard to tell which dependency should be in which `requirements*.txt` file.

If I would like to keep track of the runtime dependencies in `requirements_prod.txt` and of the development dependencies in `requirements_dev.txt`, how should I keep both files up to date and clean if I add packages during development? Running a mere `pip freeze > requirements_prod.txt` would list all installed dependencies, including those only needed for development. This would pollute either of the `requirements_*.txt` files.

Ideally, I would like to mark a package on installation as 'development' or 'runtime' and have it (and its own dependencies) written to the correct `requirements_*.txt`.

#### Edit:

**@Brian**: My question is slightly different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17803829/12646289) because I would like to have my `requirements_*.txt` files to stay side by side in the same branch, not in different branches. So my `requirements_*.txt` should always be in the same commits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize a requirements.txt for multiple environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803829/how-to-customize-a-requirements-txt-for-multiple-environments)

Comment: I think you may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43658870/4046632) useful

Comment: Usually you only want to add _direct_ dependencies to your requirements file. There's no need to list the dependencies of your dependencies since pip will find those just fine on its own. As for how to mark packages as "development" or "runtime", well, that's exactly what `requirements_prod.txt` and `requirement_dev.txt` ought to be doing. Both of those files should be maintained manually, not generated via pip freeze.

Comment: use `pipenv` and save details for dev prod stage in pip.lock file

Answer (score 1):

Brian's answer clarifies things a lot for me:

> Usually you only want to add *direct* dependencies to your requirements file.
> (...) Both of those files should be maintained manually

So instead of generating the `requirements_*.txt` file automatically using `pip freeze`, they should be maintained **manually** and only need to contain **direct dependencies**.