# Pip freeze separate test vs non test

Tags: python

I have a python project for which I want to create:

- requirements.txt -> with the modules needed for running the code but
  not the tests.
- requirements_dev.txt -> with just the extra modules
  needed for the tests.

I will reuse those in the install_requires and extras_require fields of the setup.py.

If I do a pip freeze > requirements.txt, the whole thing goes into that file. How can I separate between test vs no test?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize a requirements.txt for multiple environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803829/how-to-customize-a-requirements-txt-for-multiple-environments)

Comment: Is the question specifically about **how to determine** the requirements for the test environment? That's trivial: since the test environment conceptually **is a different environment**, simply *create a separate virtual environment for it*, configure it so that it makes the tests run, and freeze.

Comment: You can't automatically. However, you should look to `poetry` to manage better dependencies and groups.