# What usecase would there be for having two requirements.txt in a virtualenv?

Tags: virtualenv, requirements.txt

I am using a virtualenv on a server cluster to run a python library.  Getting this library to run on the cluster requires a lot of fiddling.  I was told by an ex employee they had to have two different requirements.txt files to get it to work when they did it.

Comment: Production and development like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20720019/7976758 Development one includes production.